# Message queue - server responds to only one type of message

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I am writing a server-cleint app which allows user to send communicates to server and server responds back to user. The commands are TIME (server responds with string containing current time) and END (now it is just sending some strings of text).
The thing is, the TIME command works completely fine,  server gets the message and responds. When I type in console any word that is not TIME nothing happens, program just asks for user input again. And the same thing happens when END command is used.
Example output of these programs:
Client:
[image]

Server:

[image]

Client code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "qdetails.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stddef.h>


int main()
{

struct msgbuf message;
struct msgbuf response;
char* homedir = getenv("HOME");
   key_t serverkey, ckey;
   int msgid, clientQ;

   serverkey= ftok(homedir, 65);
   ckey = ftok(homedir, 128);
   clientQ = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, 0660);
   msgid = msgget(serverkey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
   message.mtype = 1;
   printf("Server message queue id: %d \n Client queue id : %d\n", msgid, clientQ);
   sprintf(message.mtext, "%d",  clientQ);
   msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
   printf("Sent client queue id  : %s  to server queue : %d\n", message.mtext, msgid);

   while(1){
    char command[5];
    printf("Commands available: TIME for current time, END to end the program\n");
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    if(strcmp(command, "TIME")==0){
        message.mtype = 2;
        msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
        printf("TIME request sent\n");
        msgrcv(clientQ, &response, sizeof(response), 0,0);

        printf("Current time is: %s\n", response.mtext);
        printf("\n\n");
        command == "";
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "END") == 0 ){
        message.mtype = 3;
        msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
        } else {
        continue;
        }

   }
}
```

Server looks like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "qdetails.h"
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

   char* homedir = getenv("HOME");
   struct msgbuf message;
   struct msgbuf send;
   send.mtype = 4;
   key_t serverkey;
   int msgqid;


   serverkey = ftok(homedir, 65);
   msgqid = msgget(serverkey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
   printf("Server queue is active, queue id: %d ", msgqid);
    if((msgrcv(msgqid, &message, sizeof(message), 0, 0) == -1)){
      perror("Failed to receive message");
      }

    printf("Received Message is : %s \n", message.mtext);
   while(1){




   if((msgrcv(msgqid, &message, sizeof(message), 0, 0) == -1)){
      perror("Failed to receive message");
      }


    if(message.mtype == 2){
    printf("TIME request received\n");
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    assert(strftime(s, sizeof (s), "%c", tm));
    sprintf(send.mtext, "%s", s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    int to = atoi(message.mtext);
    printf("%d",to);
        if((msgsnd(to, &send, sizeof(send),0)==-1)){
        perror("Error while responding");
        }

   } else if(message.mtype == 3){
    printf("END request received\n");
     int to = atoi(message.mtext);
     strcpy("Respond from server: ", send.mtext);
     if(msgsnd(to, &send, sizeof(send), 0) == -1){
        printf("Error while responding to END request\n");
     }
    }
   }
   msgctl(msgqid, IPC_RMID, NULL); //destroy the message queue
   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what is missing here, appreciate every kind of advice

Comment: `fgets` stores the trailing newline. So when you enter `END` it stores `"END\n"`. Which means `strcmp(command, "END")` will not match. Note that `"TIME"` works because the array is `5` bytes which means `fgets` will not read the newline.

Comment: Oh, okay. I tried to somehow change the    ```"\n"``` to 0 but it did not work. Also tried changing fgets to scanf, server gets both commands but responses with some strange things...